# In my Flutter Project, Firestore Database is returning uid instead of phoneNumber

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Firebase Database i updated Phone Number with phoneNumber whereas it was returning uid.

But when i check is contact numbers in my Emulator and Firebase Database phoneNumber i found the Firebase Database is returning uid.

Firebase Database SS is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyuVL.png)

My code is

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/common/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/screens/mobile_chat_screen.dart';

final selectContactsRepositoryProvider = Provider(
  (ref) => SelectContactRepository(
    firestore: FirebaseFirestore.instance,
  ),
);

class SelectContactRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  SelectContactRepository({
    required this.firestore,
  });

  Future<List<Contact>> getContacts() async {
    List<Contact> contacts = [];
    try {
      if (await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
        contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return contacts;
  }

  void selectContact(Contact selectedContact, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      var userCollection = await firestore.collection('users').get();
      bool isFound = false;

      for (var document in userCollection.docs) {
        var userData = UserModel.fromMap(document.data());
        String selectedPhoneNum = selectedContact.phones[0].number
            .replaceAll(
              ' ',
              '',
            )
            .replaceAll(
              '-',
              '',
            );

        print('selectedPhoneNum');
        print(selectedPhoneNum);
        print('userData');     
        print(userData.phoneNumber); // printing uid

        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 60));

        if (selectedPhoneNum == userData.phoneNumber) {
          isFound = true;
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            MobileChatScreen.routeName,
            arguments: {
              'name': userData.name,
              'uid': userData.uid,
            },
          );
        }
      }

      if (!isFound) {
        showSnackBar(
          context: context,
          content: 'This number does not exist on this app.',
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context: context, content: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

My To inspect the whole project my github link is https://github.com/Jabidgithub/App-with-backend-/tree/ErrorOnEmulator

Comment: Please do not include links in questions. Links are not searchable and if it breaks it will make the question useless to future readers. Include a screen shot of your structure. What does your `UserModel` look like?

Comment: I solved the problem. It was happening due to weak internet connection due to old emulator :D